# WiredTiger error (28): No space left on device

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am using mongodb in a high i/o system and I am facing the following problem :

> `2017-08-20T12:40:47.258+0000 E STORAGE [thread2] WiredTiger error (28) [1503232847:252478][1499:0x7f9b34af7700], file:index-7-5300684995096143824.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /var/lib/mongodb/index-7-5300684995096143824.wt: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write 20480 bytes at offset 178524160: No space left on device 2017-08-20T12:40:47.258+0000 E STORAGE [thread2] WiredTiger error (28) [1503232847:258665][1499:0x7f9b34af7700], file:index-7-5300684995096143824.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: index-7-5300684995096143824.wt: fatal checkpoint failure: No space left on device 2017-08-20T12:40:47.258+0000 E STORAGE [thread2] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1503232847:258687][1499:0x7f9b34af7700], file:index-7-5300684995096143824.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic 2017-08-20T12:40:47.259+0000 I - [conn67] Fatal Assertion 28559 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 64 2017-08-20T12:40:47.259+0000 I - [thread2] Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 361 2017-08-20T12:40:47.259+0000 I - [conn34] Fatal Assertion 28559 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger`

Here is my db stat:

> `db.stats(); { "db" : "Test", "collections" : 14, "views" : 0, "objects" : 54715317, "avgObjSize" : 1364.7944367936313, "dataSize" : 74675160249, "storageSize" : 23993229312, "numExtents" : 0, "indexes" : 24, "indexSize" : 3197218816, "ok" : 1 }`

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: If you do post a question on DBA StackExchange, please provide more details about the environment and your question beyond the "no space left on device" message. For example: are you actually out of disk space in your `dbpath` or do you believe this to be a spurious message? What sort of MongoDB deployment are you running (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster) and what are your specific versions of MongoDB server and O/S? What filesystem are you using? If you've run out of free disk space in your `dbpath`, the error message is self explanatory. If not, we need more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

> No space left on device

Make sure you've free up some space on your device, then make sure the file permissions are correct (read and write access).

If you believe the database could be corrupted after than, run:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker on Windows 10 you should check the following:

1. Open your Docker Desktop App
2. Open Resources > Advanced then scroll down
3. Inspect `Disk Image size: (100%) used
4. On the very bottom you can change the location e.G in my case another drive and increase the storage you want to provide to Docker.

Restart your Docker environment.